# How to instrument code using OpenTracing / OpenCensus?

Tags: datadog, jaeger, opentracing, distributed-tracing, opencensus

I have to instrument our java/python/c++ application using one of the apis (opentracing/opencensus). The problem is that the instrumentation requires that i start a span, set tags, set logs and then close the span in each method call. This is too much change for us. Can anyone help in solving this problem ? how do i achieve this without polluting my code with all the instrumentation code ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the automatic instrumentation libraries available for OpenTracing or OpenTelemetry, as they will handle some of this for you.

- [OpenTracing Java SpecialAgent](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-specialagent)
- [OpenTelemetry Java Automatic Instrumentation](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation)

You can also check the [OpenTracing Registry](https://opentracing.io/registry) and the [OpenTelemetry Registry](https://opentelemetry.io/registry) to see if open source instrumentation packages exist for libraries or frameworks that you're using to reduce some of the boilerplate.